# Let $ \ \phi \ $ be a multiplicative partition of a group G

Tags: group-theory

Let $ \ \phi  \ $ be a multiplicative partition of a group G. Show that $ \ \phi=G/[e] \ $ , where $ \ G/[e] \ $ is the cells of equivalence relation : $\ \ a \sim_{e} b \ \  \ \ if \ \ \ a^{-1}b \in [e] $  and e is the indentity. $$ $$ I know that if H is a subgroup of a group G and if we define the relation $ \ \sim \ $ by $ \ a \sim b \ $ if $ \ a^{-1}b \in H $ , then this relation is an equivalence relation . The **cells** of this equivalence relation is the patition $ \{gH: g \in G \} $ and we denote $ G/H=\{gH: g \in G \} $. Now approaching in the same way , we have $ \ G/[e] \ $ is the **cells** of the equivalence $ \ a \sim_{[e]}b \ $ if $ \  a^{-1}b \in [e] \ $ , where $ e $ is the identity element of the group  $G $. Now we know the following three results : \begin{align} Let \ \ \phi \ \ be \  \ a \ \ multiplicative  \ \ partition \ \ of \ the \ group \ G . \ Then\\ 1. \ The \ map \ \ \pi_{\phi}: G \rightarrow \phi  \ defined \ by \ \ \pi_{\phi}(g)=[g] \ \ \forall \ g \in G \ is \ a \ homomorphism. \\ 2.  \ \  \ \ The \ \ \ partition \ \ \  \phi \  \ \ forms \ \ \  a \ \ \ group \ \     \ \ \ \ \ 
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \   \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \   \ \  . \\ 3. \  \ \ [e] \ \ \ is \ \ a \ \ subgroup \ \ of \ \ G \  \ \  \ \ \  \  \ \ \ \  \  \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \    \ \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ .  \end{align}. By definition of $ \ \phi \ $  is the cells of the equivalence relation $ \pi_{\phi} $ .   **Now  if  we can show that the two equivalence relation are same , then we will have $ \ \phi=G/[e] \ \ $. But I  got stuck right here to show that these two equivalence relations are same. Any help is appreciating .**

Comment: I guess multiplicativity of the partition means that if you have one element $\{m_1,\ldots,m_k\}$ of the partition, then for each $g\in G$, $\{gm_1,\ldots,gm_k\}$ is another element.

Comment: yes sir, but I need help only proving that the two equivalence relation  are same that will complete the proof (see my approach ).

Comment: so would you help me showing that the two equivalence relation are same ? Thank you

Comment: I'd show first that $H=[e]$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: yes it is given that $ [e] $ is subgroup of G.